# Lebesgue integrable implies measurable.

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we define Lebesgue integral [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188168/another-definition-of-lebesgue-integral), but without assuming that $f$ is measurable. Suppose there exists a finite integral $\int_Xfd\mu$. Does it follow that $f$ is measurable?

**UPD.** $f$ is integrable, if $\Xi(f) = \xi(f)$.

Comment: A guess really: There is a sequence of (finite) partitions $\pi_i=\{A^i_1,\cdots,A^i_{k_i}\}$ of $X$ together with their corresponding coefficients $a^i_k$ such that $\lim_i \xi(f,\pi_i) = \xi(f)$. There is another sequence of partitions that realize $E(f)$. Now, Construct a new sequence of partitions from intersecting the two partitions at each step. I think then you can show that $f = \lim_i \sum_k a^i_k\chi_{A^i_k}$ a.e. Since each finite sum $\sum_k a^i_k\chi_{A^i_k}$ is measurable, their limit is as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attemp to develop [Behnam Esmayli's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/283487/behnam-esmayli) idea.

$f$ is Lebesgue integrable $\implies (\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists P_{\epsilon}: E = \sqcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i)\quad U(P_{\epsilon}, f) - L(P_{\epsilon}, f) < \epsilon$, where
$U(P_{\epsilon},f) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sup_{E_i}f(x)\mu(E_i), \quad L(P_{\epsilon},f) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\inf_{E_i}f(x)\mu(E_i)$.

Define for $\epsilon = 1, \frac{1}{2}, ..., \frac{1}{n}, ... \quad h_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\inf_{E_i}f(x)*\chi_{E_i}(x)$, $h_n(x) \leq h_{n+1}(x) \leq f(x)$, $h_n(x)$ is measurable.

Similarly $g_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sup_{E_i}f(x)*\chi_{E_i}(x).$ Then $(\exists N \in \mathbb {N})(\forall x \in E) \quad f(x) -h(x) < g(x) - h(x) < \frac{1}{n}$, thus $h_n(x) \rightrightarrows f(x)$, and since $h_n(x)$ is measurable, $f(x)$ is also measurable.

Any critics, please.

Comment: Your proof is wrong. Your second to last sentence is a wrong conclusion from your premises/definitions.

Answer (score 0):

So if you can construct a non-measurable set $A \subset (0,1)$ and a function

$f(x)= 1$ for $x \in A$

$f(x)=-1$ for $-x \in A$

$f(x)=0$ $otherwise$

over the interval [-1,1]. f is an odd function so if you can define the integral without measurable f this has a good chance of having a defined integral of 0 over [-1,1].

If your definitions force the preimage of 1 to be measurable it is likely those same restrictions will force f to be measurable.